# How to undo sys.path.append(pathToModule)

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pythonpath, sys.path

I have been trying to fix the python path on my cpu, and I originally was just trying to change my `.bash_profile`, but that wasn't working, so I used

```
import sys
sys.pat.append(path/To/Module)
```

and now when I run my script, I get this error message

How can I either fix this issue or undo the `sys.path.append(path/To/Module)`?

Also, is it possible to export multiple directories in the python path, and if so how do I do that?

Comment: Remove that line?  appending to `sys.path` should only change the lookup path for the run duration of that script.  It won't affect other scripts...

Comment: Generally, mucking with `sys.path` indicates a serious design flaw, the default paths should suffice. But your error looks related to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or better, `-rpath`) actually.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you add a path with sys.path.append() you do this only for the current session. No need to undo it.

Just remove the line from you python file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sys.path.pop()`
That will remove the last item that you added or indeed the last item on the PYTHONPATH, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I either fix this issue or undo the >sys.path.append(path/To/Module)?

To undo the `sys.path.append`, you just need to remove that line from your script. Since the path is only modified for your current script and not system wide until you edit the `PYTHONPATH`.

> Also, is it possible to export multiple directories in the python path, and if so how do I do that?

If you want to do it using `sys`, you can do it like:
`sys.path.extend(['/path1', '/path2'])`

Answer (score 0):

recently I found that pycharm ide will automatically append certain directory to your sys.path if you marked that directory as Sources Root. So even if you use `sys.path.pop(sys.path.index(**directory path**)`, it wouldn't work. Just unmark the folder and the issue will be solved.